# SQL Server sum with a where or having condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm hoping this makes sense as what I'm trying to do is SUM rows based on other columns of existing rows. I have tried a couple different ways and what I hope is now close is what I have here. This is not my full SQL but hopefully this small example will get me on track

```
SELECT Price,SUM(Item) from table where Price >= Price group by Price

Sample Data
| PRICE | ITEM  |
|-------|-------|
|  1.00 |     5 |
|  2.00 |     9 |
|  3.00 |     2 |

Hopeful Result
| PRICE | ITEM  |
|-------|-------|
|  1.00 |     5 |
|  2.00 |    14 |
|  3.00 |    16 |
```

The actual result is more or less the sample data which I would expect as I am grouping by Price so it makes sense that it returns the rows like this. I just can't seem to think of away to include Price in my select without having to group or use an aggregate on it. I'm thinking I could maybe do this type of calculation with an inner select but I'm hoping there is a different way as my actual query has a lot of joins which could get messy if I go this route.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL server 2012...

```
Select price, item, sum(item) OVER(order by price rows unbounded preceding) as runningtotal
from sample
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36e9f/1/0

Comment: I'm so glad that I have the 2012 version. This is very slick.

Comment: [OVER analytic functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) offer tremendous value when needing to get results independent of the main query (windowed results); running totals, calculations on subsets of data, etc.  Incredibly powerful and worth learning how and when to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a sub-query, but a more efficient way might be to use a `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`. It depends on your specific data. I provide both methods of doing that below... See which one runs faster based on your specific data.

**Sub-query method**

```
SELECT DISTINCT op.Price, (SELECT SUM(ip.Item) FROM table ip WHERE ip.Price <= op.Price) as ITEM FROM table op ORDER BY op.Price ASC
```

**Outer-apply method**

```
SELECT DISTINCT op.Price, a.Items
FROM table op
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(ip.Item) as Items FROM TABLE ip WHERE ip.Price <= op.Price) a
ORDER BY op.Price ASC
```

Comment: So if I my actual select was something like "SELECT DISTINCT op.Price, a.Items
FROM table op left join table2 t2 on op.Id = t2.Id" would I have to include this all in the second select inside the outer apply?

Comment: Yes, if it is needed to get the numbers it would have to be included in the APPLY query. Basically, APPLY is a more performant way of doing sub-queries because it allows SQL Server to cache it into a function for the duration of the query - letting it run MUCH faster.

Comment: If you really have a lot of data (hundreds of thousands of rows), you might want to add WITH (NOLOCK) to all of the queries (NOLOCK has implications, though). Or, you might want to put the data into a table variable or temp table to make it run faster. If you'd like to take that route, let me know and I will update my answer with examples on how to get even faster performance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to do something like below. use a `self join` with the same table.

See a [DEMO Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05ae08/16)

```
SELECT t1.Price, SUM(t2.Item)
FROM   table1 t1,
       table1 t2
WHERE t2.Price <= t1.Price
GROUP BY t1.Price
ORDER BY t1.price;
```